# Add custom base-map in Carto.com

Tags: wms, carto, debugging

**PROBLEM:** The functionality **'Insert your WMS/WMTS URL'** in the **'Add a custom base-map'** menu does not work and cannot be debugged properly.

**BACKGROUND:** Following the instructions at [CARTODB MAKES IT EASY TO ADD THE PERFECT BASEMAP TO YOUR DATA VISUALIZATION](https://carto.com/blog/cartodb-makes-it-easy-to-add-the-perfect-basemap-to) I am attempting to add a WMS as a basemap. The WMS that I am using is [dem_hillshades](https://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/gebco08_hillshade/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS) which I have copied from [NOAA](https://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/index.html). Having tested the WMS in my browser (Chrome) and desktop GIS (QGIS) I can confirm that it works without problems in those clients.

**ERROR:** I am receiving the following error from carto.com **'The URL is either invalid or contains unsupported projections'**.

First of all the URL is not invalid since it has been tested in the browser & desktop GIS and also having tried a `GetMap` request using the same link and adding the 'SRS=4326' parameter which is what carto.com supports does not address the problem.

Any ideas of similar experiences would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: 
https://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/gebco08_hillshade/MapServer/WmsServer

instead of this

https://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/arcgis/services/gebco08_hillshade/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

Hope it works...

Comment: Hi Sam,

Thanks for your suggestion; it seems to be working fine so this is great news!

How did you make sense of all this though? 

I want to add more base maps in carto.com which are currently published by Geoserver and are behind basic username:password authentication or authentication keys. Is that going to cause a problem with carto?

Any examples around?

D.

Comment: Glad it worked Dimitris. 
Have a look at this comment https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/5526
I haven't tried any secured wms with cartodb but I know that you can use the leaflet library to load the secured WMS layer and then combine it with the cartodb API to produce your final map. But I am afraid that anyone with a basic knowledge of Javascript could find out the credentials you have used.

Comment: Thanks for the link Sam! The issue seems unresolved although some solution is suggested by one user. The leaflet / Carto API combination is sound but wont satisfy the crowd that I will be addressing (I.E decision makers with some understanding of GIS but no development experience). These little things make Carto seem meh :)